continue enumerate with nested itemize beamer
I was working on a frame with both enumerate and itemize, I have three main points handle by the enumerate with a couple of details each.
I wish to have my enumerate command to keep track of the numbering, so I followed this approach. However, I'm not sure why, it seems to not be working properly... maybe because I don't handle correctly the itemize within each enumerate? Below a MWE, essentially numbering "should" be sequential, whereas details have their own bullet shape.
Thanks in advance!
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\useoutertheme[width=0pt,height=.5in]{sidebar}

\usepackage{pifont}

\definecolor{bground}{HTML}{005EB8}
\definecolor{anti-flashwhite}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=anti-flashwhite,bg=bground}

\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\frametitle{Title:}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.95\textheight}
\only<1-3>{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-3> some text
    \vskip .5in
    \begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{2.5\baselineskip}
        \item[\ding{70}]<2> detail 1
        \item[\ding{70}]<3> detail 2
    \end{itemize}
    \seti
    \end{enumerate}
}
\only<4-6>{
    \begin{enumerate}
    \conti
    \item<4-6> some other text
    \vskip .5in
    \begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{2.5\baselineskip}
        \item[\ding{70}]<5> explanation 1
        \item[\ding{70}]<6> explanation 2
    \end{itemize}
    \seti
    \end{enumerate}
}
\only<7-9>{
\begin{enumerate}
    \conti
    \item<7-9> some remarks
    \vskip .5in
    \begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{2.5\baselineskip}
        \item[\ding{70}]<8> remark 1
        \item[\ding{70}]<9> remark 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


You won't have to worry about resuming the enumerate counter if you use a single enumerate environment:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=structure.fg,fg=white}
\usepackage{pifont}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title:}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\rule{0cm}{2.5\baselineskip}\ding{70}}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item<only@1-3> some text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2> detail 1
        \item<3> detail 2
    \end{itemize}
    \item<only@4-6> some other text
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<5> explanation 1
        \item<6> explanation 2
    \end{itemize}
    \item<only@7-9> some remarks
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<8> remark 1
        \item<9> remark 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}

\end{frame}

\end{document}



great thanks! Sorry, I just overcomplicated things.
